# How to use a tikz image as label in enumerate?

Tags: tikz-pgf, lists, enumerate

Is there a way to use a TikZ image as a label of enumerate?

Can I use something like the snippet below as a "styled enumeration"?

```
\newcommand\custlabel[1]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[circle, fill=blue] (A) {#1};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
```

Comment: yes, have a look at [Good way to make \textcircled numbers?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7032)

Comment: can you confirm if the link I provided resolved the issue? if so, we might close this is as a duplicate- if your question is a follow-up, please provide more details :)

Comment: @cmhughes yes, it helped, sorry. I've got some issues with it (to use in combination with other things), but this question is answered indeed.

Comment: @cmhughes How could I have found the referenced question?

Comment: Sometimes it isn't easy to find a particular question. Usually, when I link questions, I remember having seen it before, something like "when I wanted to do _X_, there was question _Y_, using the construct _Z_ to solve, and that might be usable here". So often you don't find a particular question unless you've seen it before, mostly because it uses a wording different from yours.

Comment: @TomBombadil Strictly speaking: my question is not a duplicate of any other, but an answer would be? :)

Comment: You might put it that way ;) I have this quite often, when trying to solve a problem, I remember an answer which I can use or at least adapt.

Comment: If you google `latex enumerate circled site: tex.stackexchange.com` the link I provided is the first one. I agree that finding these questions is hard, but don't worry, that's one of the reasons our community is so strong :)

Comment: @cmhughes because of the fact, that I needed to use TikZ and only the MWE was circled I searched for `latex enumerate tikz site: tex.stackexchange.com` - not as much luck. I was asking because I'm considering to flag this duplicate for moderators as "keep or merge" (or something similar). Without this topic the answer for my question is really hard to find (so thanks again for pointing at the right direction).

Comment: @cmhughes oh, I see [now](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/685/deleting-really-exact-duplicates) that dupes are not deleted or merged here, so it is not necessary. :)

Comment: Related: [writing inside a ball in a itemize/enumerate in Beamer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/72813/writing-inside-a-ball-in-a-itemize-enumerate-in-beamer)