# list of references using circled numbering

Tags: bibliographies, circles

In my document, I would like to use something that looks like the picture in my list of references

[image]

Any ideas on how to implement this?

Thank you!

This is my template

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany]{report}
\usepackage{pifont} %bouni
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{newlfont}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\newcommand\encercle[1]{%
    \unitlength1em%
    \begin{picture}(1.5,1.5)%
        \put(0.75,0.3){\circle{1.5}}% modifier 0.3 éventuellement
        \put(0,0){\parbox[b]{1.5em}{\centering#1}}%
    \end{picture}}


\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{calc}%pour encadrer un paragraphe
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=3cm, left=3cm, right=3cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{citeblue}{rgb}{0.00,0.00,0.60}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,pagebackref=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{urlcolor=citeblue, citecolor=citeblue, linkcolor=citeblue}

\begin{document}
\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem{doug} R.G. Douglas, \textit{On majorization, factorization and range inclusion of operators in Hilbert space}, Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. \textbf{17}, 413--416, 1966.

\bibitem{fg}{M. Faghih-Ahmadi, F. Gorjizadeh,} {A-numerical radius of A-normal operators in semi-Hilbertian spaces,} Italian journal of pure and applied mathematics n. 36-2016 (73-78).
    
\end{thebibliography}

But I want to obtain this form automatically 
\begin{enumerate}
\item[\encercle{1}] R.G. Douglas, \textit{On majorization, factorization and range inclusion of operators in Hilbert space}, Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. \textbf{17}, 413--416, 1966.
\item[\encercle{2}] {M. Faghih-Ahmadi, F. Gorjizadeh,} {A-numerical radius of A-normal operators in semi-Hilbertian spaces,} Italian journal of pure and applied mathematics n. 36-2016 (73-78).
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you producing the bibliography manually as in your example, or are you using `bibtex` and a particular bibliography style?

Answer (score 5):

Using biblatex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{%
\textcircled{\scriptsize #1}}
\addbibresource{report.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Of course, for a larger list of references you will need something  more sofisticated that `\textcircled` to format `labelnumberwidth` (for some ideas using `tikz`, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/72814/11604)).

Using just `thebibliography` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\@biblabel#1{\textcircled{\scriptsize #1}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{doug} R.G. Douglas, \textit{On majorization, factorization and range inclusion of operators in Hilbert space}, Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. \textbf{17}, 413--416, 1966.
\bibitem{fg}{M. Faghih-Ahmadi, F. Gorjizadeh,} {A-numerical radius of A-normal operators in semi-Hilbertian spaces,} Italian journal of pure and applied mathematics n. 36-2016 (73-78).
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't like to use ''biblatex''

Comment: @Student Updated, but you should  like biblatex `;)`